# How to serve a continuous live video stream from multiple peers?

Tags: javascript, c#

I am trying to build a video calling feature, where multiple browser clients will be joining a meeting and each one will be uploading their media stream to the server.

The server should take each stream, merge it into an ongoing virtual file/stream.

We have already have webRTC/Signalr working, however the reason we want to move to server is because some people have poor internet and are not able to upload to multiple peers using webRTC. So we want to switch to them just uploading to the single server, which then allows the peers to stream a single media stream.

The challenge I have is, I want to be able to append the multiple streams to a single media stream that is ongoing. eg if two people are on a call, but a third joins, I need to be able to append their media seamlessly.

Any advise on where to begin?

I know we could write to a physical file and stream the file, but this would cause the stream to restart every time there is a change.

I have the below sample code that serves a physical file as stream to clients.

```
public async void WriteContentToStream(Stream outputStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext) {  
//path of file which we have to read//  
var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/MicrosoftBizSparkWorksWithStartups.mp4");  
//here set the size of buffer, you can set any size  
int bufferSize = 1000;  
byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];  
//here we re using FileStream to read file from server//  
using(var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)) {  
    int totalSize = (int) fileStream.Length;  
    /*here we are saying read bytes from file as long as total size of file 

    is greater then 0*/  
    while (totalSize > 0) {  
        int count = totalSize > bufferSize ? bufferSize : totalSize;  
        //here we are reading the buffer from orginal file  
        int sizeOfReadedBuffer = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, count);  
        //here we are writing the readed buffer to output//  
        await outputStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, sizeOfReadedBuffer);  
        //and finally after writing to output stream decrementing it to total size of file.  
        totalSize -= sizeOfReadedBuffer;  
    }  
}
```

}

How would I serve a virtual file/stream instead?

Answer (score 0):

A good option for this would be using an **SFU** (Selective Forwarding Unit) or an **MCU** (Multipoint Conferencing Unit).
With an MCU all streams are sent to the server to then be merged and retransmitted as a single stream. This method is very resource intensive though.

A good other option would be using an SFU where every connected user only needs to send their streams to the server. This would drastically reduce the upload bandwidth used. Then all streams can be separately received from the server from the other users.

(performance) As you want to reduce the bandwidth there is also **simulcast** which makes multiple streams of different quality available from the server. This automatically chooses the best streams based on the users device. (there is an implementation of this in the example project below).

(recording+merging) [Mediasoup](https://mediasoup.org) is one of the SFU libraries and can be used and can also send rtp streams. It's possible to send streams to **ffmpeg** to be saved to a file or later on combined for later usage for example.

SFU libraries: [Mediasoup](https://mediasoup.org), [Janus Gateway](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/), [Kurento](https://www.kurento.org/)

Example projects: [Mediasoup video conferencing](https://github.com/Dirvann/mediasoup-sfu-webrtc-video-rooms), [Mediasoup recording](https://github.com/ethand91/mediasoup3-record-demo)